# Connect to QtCreator .ui file directly to visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt

Our team is using visual studio to write a whole project, and the user interface is made with Qt Designer to form a .ui file.

I wonder if there is a way to connect the .ui file directly into the c++ file in visual studio instead of in qtcreator. Also, I want to load the .ui file at runtime instead of qmake it into .cpp or .h file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For UI file integration in Visual Studio, have a look at the [Qt Visual Studio Add-In](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtVSAddin).

For loading UI files at runtime, have a look at the [QUiLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

- Even the VisualStudio-integration will not integrate Qt's editor into VisualStudio. You can edit *.ui*'s text content in VisualStudio's editor, but not the designer-editor. Thus, to layout and preview *.ui*, you have to open the .ui-files in seperate app (designer.exe or QtCreator)
- Is is uncommon to load the *.ui* Files at runtime: Usually, you have a compile-step on the *.ui* File (which calls 'uic.exe'). - The so generated .cpp and .h files are compiled (at compiletime of course). You do not use the *.ui* at runtime. But...:
- The generated .cpp/.h code contains Qt-Widgets. You can implement an interface for the widgets to be loaded at runtime. A good example for this is [QtDesigner](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtdesigner.html). The designer.exe loads widgets this way... at runtime!